# Browser not sending form data?

Tags: python, post, cgi, browser-cache

I have a web form which includes a button to submit a small text file and a text field via `POST` to a Python CGI script, which uses `cgi.FieldStorage`. The script processes the file, but first checks that the text field occurs in the file. If the file does not contain the text from the text field, the script displays an error page to the user.

One user (Windows XP with a recent Firefox; also tested later with Internet Explorer) is experiencing a problem with the web page. The script is reporting that the file does not contain the text field, when in fact it does. I tested this myself on the user's computer. Only after hard-refreshing (Ctrl-F5) the page, completing the form again and submitting it, did the script display the required output instead of the error. This user has experienced this problem more than once, on different days after restarting the computer between sessions. Clearing the browser cache files did not solve the problem.

What could be causing this? Is the browser sending old form data or no form data?

**Edit:** The user is now experiencing a problem where the script is reporting that the file is in the wrong format. The script will report this if it receives an empty file or if it cannot open the file. Clearly the browser is not sending all the form data? We tested with Internet Explorer too, which exhibits the same problem. This is Windows problem?

Comment: Try to use FireBug addon in Firefox where you can see what browser send to server.

Comment: @Denis: Ok, I'll see if I can install that on the user's machine and test it from there, as I cannot reproduce the problem elsewhere.